# Рецепт торта или рецепт приготовления торта?

Tags: грамотная-речь

В Сети предлагают РЕЦЕПТЫ РАЗНЫХ БЛЮД, и никто не сомневается в правильности этого сочетания.

А вот в толковом словаре Кузнецова на Грамоте.ру (2014 ГОД) дается такое определение: РЕЦЕПТ  2. Указания о способе изготовления, приготовления чего-л. Р. варки стекла. Р. пива. Р. засолки огурцов. Узнать р. ПРИГОТОВЛЕНИЯ торта.

Так когда нужно говорить о "приготовлении" чего-либо или есть случаи, когда  это слово является лишним?

Comment: Лишнее это слово. Формально допустимо, но избыточно, вот прямо  как  www после http.

Comment: А как правильно: рецепт засолки огурцов или рецепт соленых огурцов?

Comment: ИМХО оба варианта верны - если рецепт правильный. "Рецепт этих 
 солёных огурцов - наш семейный секрет"

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, Вы очень убедительны.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Понятно, что вариант "рецепт торта" самодостаточен без всякого "приготовления". 
Вопрос в том только, признавать ли вариант Кузнецова неудачным (избыточным) или принципиально неверным (тавтологичным).

Я думаю, Кузнецов тут неправ, с ним это бывает. И потом, у него все-таки словарь **толковый**, а примеры правильного использования - это немного другая епархия. Тавтологичность, мне кажется, присутствует, слово "рецепт" уже несет значение "изготовление", синонимичное в данном случае "приготовлению" у Кузнецова. Сам же Кузнецов это и подтверждает.

> РЕЦЕПТ, -а; м. [от лат. receptum - взятое, принятое] 1. Письменное
>
> предписание врача в аптеку о составе лекарства с указанием способа его
>   применения. Приготовить капли в соответствии с рецептом. Препарат
>   отпускается только по рецепту врача. // Предписание врача в мастерскую
>   об изготовлении элементов протезирования. Выписать р. на новые очки.
>   2. Указания о способе изготовления, приготовления чего-л. Р. варки стекла. Р. пива. Р. засолки огурцов. Узнать р. приготовления торта.
>   Выдержать все пропорции рецепта. Кулинарные рецепты. 3. Разг.
>   Руководство, совет, как действовать, поступать в том или ином случае.
>   Р. на все случаи жизни. Дать р. выхода из кризиса. У каждого свой р.
>   счастья. В воспитании нет готовых рецептов. <Рецептный, -ая, -ое. Р.
>   бланк. Р-ые книги. Рецептурный (см.).

То есть "рецепт приготовления торта" получается нечто наподобие "инструкции по изготовлению приготовления торта". Значит, у Кузнецова это рецепт не совсем торта, а лишь рецепт некой "инструкции", либо, что вернее, просто ненамеренная тарабарщина на почве косноязычия.

Бывает, что язык усваивает подобные тавтологии, но все-таки какая-то причина для подобного нужна. А тут ее нет.

Comment: Да, спасибо, я еще почитала этимологические словари. Слово из латыни:receptum - принятое обязательство, гарантия. Что-то вроде "обязуюсь, ручаюсь, гарантирую" было написано на "рецепте". Слово заимствовано из немецкого языка, в словарях с 1701 года. В англ. языке рецепт торта и медицинский рецепт - разные слова. У нас есть еще "рецептура", но оно в быту не используется. .РЕЦЕПТУРА 2. Совокупность сведений о составе и способе приготовления чего-л. Р. духов. Р. огнеупорной краски.

Comment: @Иванов7-й, адоптировать - в русском имеет очень ограниченную сферу применения. Лучше - усваивать. Я исправил после Риммы, мне очень сильно глаз резануло. Правда сам сначала запутался, на Римму наехал.